# Change css padding while collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I'm using [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). I have a div with 25 px padding. I want to remove that padding while div collapse. Can anyone help me to achieve it.

Collapse documentation [available here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden', function () {
  $('#myCollapsible').css('padding','0');
});
```

edit : errant } tag removed

Answer (score 0):

An example of your code would *really* help, but I'm assuming you are doing something like this with Bootstrap and jQuery:

```
$("#myElement").collapse();
```

Try just setting the css `padding` to `0` before you `collapse` it:

```
$("#myElement").css({padding: 0}).collapse();
```